# Trying to simplify this javascript function

Tags: javascript

I think I wrote function badly. I trying to simplify it but preserve the functionality.

```
function changeLetters(text) {
  text = text.toLowerCase();
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    var alphabet = advanced.checked ? alphabets[text[i]] || alphabets2[text[i]] : alphabets[text[i]];
    if (alphabet) {
      text = text.replace(text[i], alphabet);
    }
  }
  return text;
}
```

One approach would be something like this :

```
function changeLetters(text) {
  var alphabets = advanced.checked ? alphabets || alphabets2 : alphabets;
  return text.toLowerCase().replace(/[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
    return alphabets[letter] || letter;
  });
}
```

But the problem with second function is that it don't check `alphabet` and `alphabet2` objects even `advanced` is checked. I mean this line does nothing `advanced.checked ? alphabets || alphabets2 : alphabets`

Any way to simplify this function?
Thanks.

- demo - http://jsbin.com/AREZoCig/6/

Comment: Can you give us some inputs and expected outputs? what is `alphabets`, `alphabets2`, and `advanced`?

Comment: here it is - http://jsbin.com/AREZoCig/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `||` operator on two arrays is not the same as using it on two items from the array.

The principle of your rewrite is better, because it will not do a replace on the entire string for each character to replace, and it allows you to replace a character with another character without the risk of that being replaced later on in the loop.

You still have to do the operation on the items from the arrays in the loop:

```
function changeLetters(text) {
  return text.toLowerCase().replace(/[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
    return (advanced.checked ? alphabets[letter] || alphabets2[letter] : alphabets[letter]) || letter;
  });
}
```

Comment: is `toLowerCase()` more efficient than adding an `i` to the regex?

Comment: @JeremyMiller: Probably not, but it doesn't give the same result.

Comment: Fair enough on the same result statement. :)  Thanks for the info.